# porque recibo error ora 24247 si ya se crearon los ACL?

Tags: oracle-12c

Estoy consumiendo un WebService Rest

```
(select utl_http.request('https://172.29.20.89/auth/v1/') from dual;)
```

y recibo el error ORA24247 y ya cree los ACL.

```
en dba_network_acls
172.29.20.89  /sys/acls/ACCESS_HTTPS_PAYMENT.xml    00000000800027EC    SYS

en dba_network_acl_privileges
/sys/acls/ACCESS_HTTPS_PAYMENT.xml  00000000800027EC    MARLENE resolve true
/sys/acls/ACCESS_HTTPS_PAYMENT.xml  00000000800027EC    MARLENE connect true
```

que mas debo hacer para recibir este error.

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Podrías por favor [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477776/edit) tu pregunta y poner el mensaje de error completo que recibes? Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: podrias agregar tu ACL para ver como esta configurado?